# Ways to configure pyspark with jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have Jupiter and python in my system. Could anybody please let me know how do I use Pyspark through Jupiter? I want to use pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of guides available online.

You can follow this one
https://www.sicara.ai/blog/2017-05-02-get-started-pyspark-jupyter-notebook-3-minutes

Alternatively, you can just use the prebuilt docker image directly,
https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/pyspark-notebook/

Comment: Thank You. I am able to configure pyspark with jupyter successfully. I am trying to learn pyspark myself in this COVID-19. Could you please suggest me good resources which I can refer to like: youtube videos or good online resources.